# Edit all wp_enqueues at once

Tags: javascript, php, css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

Is there a way to change all WordPress styles and scripts to be in head instead of footer.

```
wp_enqueue_script( string $handle, string $src = '', string[] $deps = array(), string|bool|null $ver = false, bool $in_footer = false )
```

What I want is to change all scripts and styles enqueued by my theme and plugins, and place them in head. Without dequeueing them one by one and adding them again.

This means $in_footer should be changed to "false" on all occurrences.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will print all scripts from header to footer section before body tag

//Add All Script Tags into Footer Section

```
add_action('init', function () {
    remove_action('wp_head', 'wp_print_scripts');
    remove_action('wp_head', 'wp_print_head_scripts', 9);
  //  remove_action('wp_head', 'print_emoji_detection_script', 7);
    //add_action('wp_footer', 'prnt_emoji_detection_script', 5);
    add_action('wp_footer', 'wp_print_scripts', 5);
    add_action('wp_footer', 'wp_print_head_scripts', 5);
});
```